# How to track youtube video wich is present in iframe using google tag manager?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics, youtube, google-tag-manager

My page consists iframe tag which includes youtube video url. I want to track my video. means how many time video is played. using Google Tag Manager. please help me into this?

```
<iframe width="640" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video-id}}" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not able to understand it can you please give me any simple example. as I am new to Google Tag Manager?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate since youtube comes with an API that can be used for GA tracking. Lunametrics has a script with instructions at their github repo https://github.com/lunametrics/youtube-google-analytics.